# are moving average and lag modeling the same?

Tags: lags, moving-average

I am not clear on the difference between the two concepts but I am interested in air pollution exposure in a given period of time and in the literature, I know that lag models are used. I have also seen the moving average for air pollution, is this the same as lag models? If not, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both models are quite different. As described in [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice*](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos, what you call the lagged model seems to be the [*autoregressive model* (AR)](https://otexts.com/fpp3/AR.html).

> [...] an autoregressive model of order $p$ can be written as $$y_{t} = c + \phi_{1}y_{t-1} + \phi_{2}y_{t-2} + \dots + \phi_{p}y_{t-p} + \varepsilon_{t}$$ where $\varepsilon_{t}$ is white noise. This is like a multiple regression but with *lagged values* of $y_t$ as predictors. We refer to this as an AR($p$) model, an autoregressive model of order $p$.

It can be compared with the [*moving average* (MA) model](https://otexts.com/fpp3/MA.html).

> Rather than using past values of the forecast variable in a regression, a moving average model uses past forecast errors in a regression-like model, $$y_{t} = c + \varepsilon_t + \theta_{1}\varepsilon_{t-1} + \theta_{2}\varepsilon_{t-2} + \dots + \theta_{q}\varepsilon_{t-q}$$ where $\varepsilon_t$ is white noise. We refer to this as an MA($q$) model, a moving average model of order $q$. Of course, we do not *observe* the values of $\varepsilon_t$, so it is not really a regression in the usual sense.

Though, as described later in the book, under some conditions, one model can be written as another. They are usually combined in the [ARMA models](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima.html). You would more commonly see the regression with lagged values because it is easy to interpret and estimate (does not need specialized time-series software as it can be done using regular linear regression).